# Create Windows 7 Image with Drivers and Updates Installed Without Going Over the Network

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, deployment, sysprep

I was wondering if there was a way to create a Windows 7 image with updates and additional drivers (all Dell PCs) installed so it works on multiple computers?  I want to be able to do all of this without settings up special software on a server and pulling the image over a network.  If I do have to install special software is there anything that can be done on Windows 10 and not a server?

When I have the image done I would like to have it on a bootable flash drive.

Is this possible or do you need something like MDT?

Thanks!

Comment: follow this blog post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/03/06/building-windows-7-images-in-2017/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called "slipstreaming".

Try to google for "windows 7 slipstream" and you'll find tons of solutions. There are quite a few shareware and freeware tools helping you with that if you don't want to dig in too much and manually edit config files.

One of the most used ones is called NTLite, here: https://www.ntlite.com/download

Comment: This looks like it does what I want to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the older, more manual guidelines presented in a decent fashion here: https://www.howtogeek.com/255540/the-last-windows-7-iso-youll-ever-need-how-to-slipstream-the-convenience-rollup/